# LINQ Query is removing multiple rows instead of a single row

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have tried the following:

```
var itemtoremove = db.ItemGroups.Single(x => x.ID == _id);
if (itemtoremove != null)
{
    db.ItemGroups.Remove(itemtoremove);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The query 'works' but it deletes more than one row! Any ideas? The table itself is part of a set or really terrible tables, but I've got to use them. 
Can having multiple keys on a table affect what EF does?

Thanks folks.

Comment: This makes no sense. The call to `.Single` returns one row, or fails. Are you sure your problem is caused by this code?

Comment: Are you making other changes somewhere else before you call SaveChanges here?

Comment: `Single` will throw an exception if there is no match or more than one match.  So you do not need the `if` statement.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Good point, but I'd say the OP does need the `if` statement, but needs `SingleOrDefault()`. :)

Comment: It's not the query but the `.SaveChanges()` method that removes all entities that was detached or deleted from context either from this code or outside of it. It looks like the problem lays somewhere else. Provide more related code please

Comment: The code is executed only once. I also think it is perfectly fine. But, as soon as the Changes Are Saved two rows (with different ID fields) vanish! I'm banging my head against my desk! A CHAR(6) fields called GroupID is set as a PK on the table, and a CHAR(7) field called 'Code' is also set as a PK. In desperation I've added an ID (Identifier - auto) field to it, but still both rows with GroupID 227 are removed. I can only assume it's the table itself causing it.

Comment: oops, it seems strange and intresting :) please paste the sql that is generated by entity framework and let us see that. (you can get entity framework profiler from codeplex).

Answer (score 2):

If the enitity has a navigation property and you have not set CascadeOnDelete(false); you could potentially remove more than one item.

```
//check item group for duplicates (just as a test)
var items = db.ItemGroups.Where(x => x.ID == _id); //breakpoint here to make sure there is only one match. If there is only one then you are deleting a linked item to the entity you are deleting.

var itemtoremove = db.ItemGroups.Single(x => x.ID == _id);
if (itemtoremove != null)
{
    db.ItemGroups.Remove(itemtoremove);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolution.
I think with the table having 2 PK's setup on it (both on CHAR fields) was causing EF to become confused. The table goes back years and it is part of a group of tables that do not relate to one another properly. It's pretty poor but that's another story!

So, I started from scratch again:

After re-importing the table in it's original format I did the following:

- Removed the PK on 'GroupID' (should never have been a PK)
- Added an ID column, set it as 'IsIdentity' so it will auto-generate an ID
- refreshed my EF Model to include:

  ```
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  ```

Now only the one correct row is removed when the SaveChanges is applied.

Thanks for your suggestions folks!